# How to avoid using multiple PUSH over array in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, push

I am trying to loop over arrays of object and need to push out some values to new array based on some checks. I don't find the way i am doing now is efficient way to handle case. Any other good approach i can take. I am basically using Push multiple times. And that is what i want to reduce or remove.
Below Result output is to show into graph.

Sample Data

```
{
    activity_one: [
    {
        _id: ObjectID(9473),
        user_id: ObjectID(39279),
        star_rating:5,
        create_at: time_stamp,
        activity_context: {
            _id:"",
            activity_id:""
        },
        activity: {},
        name: Bingo,
        image:""
    }, 
    {some_data}
    ],
    activity_two: [
        {some_data}, {some_data}
    ],
    etc
}
```

Code

```
const results = {
        number_of_ratings: {
            lables: [],
            data: [],
        },
        average_ratings: {
            lables: [],
            data: [],
        },
        activity_over_time: {
            lables: ['time'],
            data: [],
        },
    };
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sampleData)) {
        results.number_of_ratings.lables.push(key); // activity_one
        results.number_of_ratings.data.push(value.length); // value = [{},{}] -> array of objects

        results.average_ratings.lables.push(key);
        results.average_ratings.data.push(lodash.meanBy(value, (p) => p.star_rating));

        results.activity_over_time.lables.push(key);
        value.map((rating) => {
        // lodash.mapValues(value, (p) =>
            results.activity_over_time.data.push(moment(rating.create_at).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS')),
            results.activity_over_time.data.push(rating.star_rating);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Kind of hard to really grasp what you're trying to do since your sample data just has `{some_data}` instead of a full example, but one thing I'm seeing is that you're pushing `key` to multiple areas. Why not simplify your `results` object to have `labels` in the root; instead of contained within each nested object? That way you only need to push `key` once.

Comment: @ElderTale I have edited sample data, hope you will get more context now. There are 2 reasons i am not moving that to top level. 1st. This data will be shown in Bar or Line chart, Above 3 objects are 3 different charts and filters are common for all charts. so key might be different for different filter i have, Lets say for date filter, out of this 3 chart, but 1 chart result has less key, so i can specifically show in that chart. 2nd. FE library will need x and y axis data to pick. so i need to have this pattern.
What i want to achieve is reduce the amount of `PUSH`.

Comment: I don't really see any way to simplify this if that's the result you need to get. However, you should use `forEach` rather than `map()` if you're not using the resulting array. BTW, you misspelled "labels".